# jQuery mobile popup on clicking an li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i am trying to get a pop up being displayed on clicking an LI element in an UL list.

here is the html part

```
<ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
</ul>

<div id="popups">
</div>
```

Elements in the #list will be dynamically generated and filled in.

Since I want a popup on clicking an element in the list, when i am inserting the element in the UL i am doing it like this

```
 $("#popups").append('<div data-role="popup" id="' + event.data.key + '">' + '<p>' + event.data.text + '</p>' + '</div>');
 $("#list").append('<li><a href="#' + event.data.key + '" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-right" >' + event.data.text + '</a></li>');
```

But what i get is this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2736804/others/2014_07_28_jQuery.PNG and nothing happens when i click the elements in the UL :(

How could i fix this?

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not show how you handle clicking on LI (in your js) but the thing with dynamically generated content is if you want to add event listeners you need to use delegate one.
So instead:

```
$('#list li').click(function() { /* your code here */ });
```

You need to use:

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li', function() { /* your code here */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to use any of the following methods,since the li's are created dynamically

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li', function() { });
```

OR

```
$('#list').delegate('li', 'click', function() { });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!

"delegate" helped me.

Here is the fix ...

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {

        $('#list').delegate('li', 'click', function() { 
        var listId = this.id;
        console.log("element id: " + listId);
        popupElement = '#'+listId+'L';
        console.log("popupElement id: " + popupElement);
        $( popupElement ).popup();
        });

    });
```